# `npm run build:prod:aot` is missing script in ng2-admin

Tags: angular, docker, web-deployment, angular2-aot, docker-image

I am creating the ng2-admin app image by this command `npm run build:prod` it creates the image successfully, but when I deploy this image on docker it keeps giving me error, so I want to run

> npm run build:prod:aot

this command to check errors by ahead of time compiling this give me script is missing error

Here is my error-log for running `npm run build:prod:aot` command

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\ali\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build:prod:aot' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v6.10.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: build:prod:aot
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Users\ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-
```

This project perfectly fine on locally

Comment: Try `ng build --prod --aot`

Comment: this work fine in angular-4 apps but this is in angular-2 (ng2-admin)  and by running this it gave this error                                                 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (D:\jalees\ng2-shopOwner\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\build.js:15:56)
    at Class.run (D:\jalees\ng2-shopOwner\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:216:26)
    at resolve (D:\jalees\ng2-shopOwner\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:261:20)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're referring to https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin , your command won't work because there is no such script in package.json.

The package.json file must include a script for "build:prod:aot" for you to be able to run it using npm.

For example; the package.json of the project above looks like this:

```
...
 "scripts": {
    ...

    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",

    ...
  },
...
```

You will need to add a line with the script that you want to execute by adding

```
"build:prod:aot": " /* script */"
```

After you add that to the package.json you will be able to run your script using `npm run build:prod:aot`.

Side note: It looks like `npm run build:prod` already uses AOT for this specific project.

Comment: I m using the older version of ng-admin2 which uses webpack instead of anglular cli

Comment: Sorry I’m not sure I understand your question;  were you asking Why the npm run build:prod:aot command didn’t work or how to do AoT compilation using webpack ?